# How do I stop someone from cyber bullying me through spam?

Tags: laptop, email, website, desktop-computer, tablet

Basically someone keeps on signing me up to all of these porn websites. I open my email and I have 10,000 emails telling me how I can grow my size, or all of these local ladies in my area who want to do dirty things with me, or beastiality. Many different things.

I have deleted them all because I have no interest in such things. I even set filters in gmail to filter them as spam. I goto the websites to remove myself from their lists, but more come quicker than I can remove. The problem is getting worse. I don't think it is just the websites enrolling me because of how quickly they are coming in. I do believe someone is purposely adding me to these sites.  I don't want to get a new email address because what is to stop them from doing this to the new one as well.  So my question is, how do I solve this?

Also please don't sign me up to any more. I am giving my email address to make this account but am afraid someone on here might spam me too...

Comment: I highly suspect this isn't a case of "cyber bullying" and more of the simple fact, spammers pay for valid email addresses, and websites sell this information to companies which sell to spammers.  Sending email is cheap, its basically free, with your own hardware.  Get a good anti-spam filter for your email and move on with your life.

Comment: You should not be going to these sites to try to resolve the spam. Especially do not click any "Unsubscribe" links in spam email you receive from sites you are unfamiliar with.

Comment: in support of @root: "unsubscribe" on these sites means "live person, possibly gullible" and they probably (read: 100% certainly) serve ad clicks (and potentially attempt to install invisible click-software) on the unsubscribe page. You are probably *increasing* your unsolicited subscribes geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can spam you.

Use a better spam filter or create a new e-mail that you keep more privately

Here's how to use google's spam filter:

EDIT:
Click the check-box next to the e-mails that you consider spam, and then mark them as spam by using the spam button
[Block unwanted emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8151?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a site you gave your email address selling it on to a spammer; once it gets sold to one it gets sold on and on until you end up with a Simulacra type case where it's impossible to find where it all started. Apart from beefing up your spam filter it's a good practice to have a junk email account that you use for things you're suspicious might be spammy such as when a WiFi connection asks for your email address to connect etc.